# Slow response of Oracle query, using functions

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have the next query:

```
SELECT to_char(xa_time_cnv.utc_to_loc(UTCTIME),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),  
                    +
                    ROUND(VALOR_INST,2),  
                    +
                    ge_pkt_conv_funcs.f_convert_tlq(TLQ_INST),  
                    +
                    ROUND(VALOR_PROM,2),  +
                    ge_pkt_conv_funcs.f_convert_tlq(TLQ_PROM),  
                    +
                    ROUND(VALOR_MAX,2),  +
                    ge_pkt_conv_funcs.f_convert_tlq(TLQ_MAX),  
                    +
                    to_char(xa_time_cnv.utc_to_loc(UTCTIME_MAX),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
                    +
                    ROUND(VALOR_MIN,2), 
                    +
                    ge_pkt_conv_funcs.f_convert_tlq(TLQ_MIN),  
                    +
                    to_char(xa_time_cnv.utc_to_loc(UTCTIME_MIN),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
                    FROM  a_5min_033 
             WHERE utctime >= xa_time_cnv.loc_to_utc(TO_DATE('27/06/2014 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),null) 
             AND   utctime <= xa_time_cnv.loc_to_utc(TO_DATE('28/06/2014 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 8/24,null) 
             AND   POINTNUMBER =  330000 
             ORDER BY utctime;
```

The first time it runs after returns records:

Elapsed: 00:00:30.87

Then, In a second run (query in cache):

Elapsed: 00:00:01.17

I tried grouping, but without results:

```
GROUP BY utctime, valor_inst, tlq_inst, valor_prom, tlq_prom, valor_max, tlq_max, utctime_max, valor_min, tlq_min, utctime_min
```

a_5min_033 have 3million of rows, aprox.

I would like to improve the response, 1st time.

Could you advise me on how to get better performance?

In the attachment, I send the script of creating the table, indexes.

Comment: Please add an execution plan (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm). How is the table defined? Any indexes?

Comment: Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 62  Bytes: 2,744  Cardinality: 49      
 4 SORT GROUP BY  Cost: 62  Bytes: 2,744  Cardinality: 49     
  3 FILTER    
   2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE XAJTDB.A_5MIN_033 Cost: 61  Bytes: 2,744  Cardinality: 49   
    1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) XAJTDB.A_5MIN_033_PK Cost: 3  Cardinality: 89

Comment: CREATE TABLE A_5MIN_033
( UTCTIME      DATE NOT NULL,
  POINTNUMBER  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SITEID       INTEGER,
  VALOR_INST   FLOAT(126) DEFAULT (0.0),
  TLQ_INST     INTEGER DEFAULT (32),
  VALOR_PROM   FLOAT(126) DEFAULT (0.0),
  TLQ_PROM     INTEGER DEFAULT (32),
  VALOR_MAX    FLOAT(126) DEFAULT (0.0),
  TLQ_MAX      INTEGER DEFAULT (32),
  UTCTIME_MAX  DATE,
  VALOR_MIN    FLOAT(126) DEFAULT (0.0),
  TLQ_MIN      INTEGER DEFAULT (32),
  UTCTIME_MIN  DATE);

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX A_5MIN_033_PK ON A_5MIN_033
(POINTNUMBER, UTCTIME)
LOGGING
NOPARALLEL;

CREATE INDEX A_5MIN_033_VALOR_INST ON A_5MIN_033
(UPPER(TO_CHAR("VALOR_INST")))
LOGGING
NOPARALLEL;

Comment: Hard to read in a comment :( ... have you tried to use two separate indexes for `POINTNUMBER` and `utctime`? Depending on cardinalities this might result in better performance. Is your query much faster if you omit the `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating an index on `(POINTNUMBER, utctime)`:

```
create index idx_a_5min_033_pointnumber_utctime on a_5min_033(POINTNUMBER, utctime);
```

The extra time initially is probably for loading the data into memory.  The timing suggests that the query is doing a fully table scan.  Note that this is speculation.  To really understand the execution path, you need to use `explain plan` or similar functionality.